# Regarding definition of convex cone and apex

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convex-geometry, convexity

I have been reading about star shaped sets and support cones from [this article](https://www.heldermann-verlag.de/jca/jca17/jca0840_b.pdf). I am wondering about the definition of the cone as to why is it defined this way? Why is it $C-a$? I am familiar with the definition given [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone). And what exactly is the apex of a cone and can you give an example of a cone whose apex does not belong to the cone.[image]

Comment: $C-a$ means the set $C-a := \{c-a\colon c\in C\}$ (this is like Minkowski sum notation). According to this definition, an example of a cone would be the open positive orthant $\{(x,y)\colon x, y >0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which has apex the origin $(0,0)$, but the origin is not in the cone.

Comment: @SamHopkins Can you give an example of a cone with more than one apex?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^2$, the half-plane $\{(x,0)\colon x \geq 0\}$ has all of the line $x=0$ as apices.

Comment: Ok. Thank you..

Comment: Sorry, I should have written "the half-plane $\{(x,y)\colon x \geq 0\}$" in the previous comment, of course.